# Some questions about the render order of the Uis in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Found something beyond my understanding.

[image: two images with a text overlapping one of them.]
two images with a text overlapping one of them.

[image: how they're ordered.]
how they're ordered.

[image: 3 batches!]
3 batches!

This is confusing me. As some official article I've read, "Unity UIs are constructed back-to-front, with objects’ order in the hierarchy determining their sort order. Objects earlier in the hierarchy are considered behind objects later in the hierarchy. Batches are built by walking the hierarchy top-to-bottom and collecting all objects which use the same material, the same texture and do not have intermediate layers."

In my understanding, the text should be rendered before the two images,and that the batches should be 2 rather than 3. So what's really happening here?

Comment: To be more specific, the three batches are : the red image -> the text -> the white image.

Comment: check the canvas sort order (in case children might have a canvas component)

Comment: Interesting. Tried to reproduce it and got the correct behavior (2 batches): https://imgur.com/a/FjLCqpK. However, order of batches is still incorrect, as the text is rendered first no matter what is its order in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Because the text is rendering first, when the square renders, it goes over top of the already drawn pixels.

"As for batches, batching means that it takes all the same elements, that have the same texture and material, and tries to put them in 1 draw call if it can. Text, on the other hand, is always in a different atlas. So if you have an Image followed by Text , you'll have 2 draw calls as they cannot be batched together." - [referenced here](https://connect.unity.com/p/ui-batching-in-unity)

You may need to enable static or dynamic batching in the Player Settings as well, if they are static, try marking them batching static in the inspector. I would refer to the link above for more of the reasons as to why batching may not work, as it seems there can be plenty of reasons!

EDIT: Are you using the default Unity text, or Text Mesh Pro? It will most likely work the same in terms of render orders and batches, but if you are not using TMP, you should be, as it is much more efficient, and renders better, and has more capabilities in general. There is a good reason Unity bought the product to adapt into their base engine.